# Ways to find how the user journey looks like in my application when 1000's of users hitting the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Sorry, I'm new to this thing. I have a .net application built on sitecore and I would like to know how the user journey looks like.I want to get the details so that I can use it to frame my performance testing or other things later.

I would like to know the following details when there is a peak load in the application(say around 10K users):

Which page of the application the user lands first and how do they navigate across the site.
Any ways to identify if it is an existing customer or new customer or someone who just visited without signing in.
It would be awesome if I can see how long the user stays on each page.

Any info would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wait, what? You don't know what the first page and the navigation is *for your own site*?  Have you tried ... looking at it?

Comment: oops..my bad... I know ...but I want to get the details during peak time so that I can use the details for performance testing and other things later.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for, it could be any of a number of things. Load testing? User identification? Site analytics? All of the above?

Comment: Have you got any kind of analytics package in use on your site e.g. Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach:

1. When any page of your website is accessed, check if cookie contains your tracking key or not.
2. If not, generate a tracking key and store it in user's machine
3. Store into a table the tracking key and current page URL

Also,

- The table should have an `autoincrement` field
- Whenever a page is accessed, the tracking key and page URL (with or without `querystring` parameters, as you wish) will be saved in the table.

When needed, scan for all tracking keys and for each tracking key, get the page URL list `ORDER BY that_autoIncrement_column`

*P.S. This approach requires use of cookies*

HTH.